# How can I use checker deselect to select separated faces?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

How can I apply the same selection pattern in image 1 to all the faces in image 2?

[image]
image 1

[image]
image 2

Comment: do you mean you're trying to select all the edges like in picture 2?

Answer (score 2):

When converting between selection modes (vertex,Edge,Face), Blender follows these rules:

- When converting to a higher order (V>E>F) the higher-order components become selected if **all** their lower-order components were selected.
- When converting to a lower order (F>E>V) all the lower-order components of previously selected higher-order components become selected.

Making use of that behavior:

1. Select 2 sequential longitudinal ***edges*** in the pattern (from the first and second regions to be selected in the end).
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad+</kbd> (Select Next Element) repeatedly to continue selecting further edges at the same interval
3. From the header *Select* menu, hit 'Select Loops'> 'Edge Rings'
4. Switch to Vertex mode.

The faces/all their edges in the regions are now implicitly selected, if you switch back between modes.

[image]

In the picture, I switched to vertex mode *before* making the edge ring selection .. that still works (by the conversion rules)